# How save the "for loop" json output to a variable without changing its format?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to scrap some data from a website and the result is json format , but i also have to do some operations with that json data so if i save that json format output of for loop to a list then format will change and i will not able to perform some operations , is there any way to store output without changing format ?

```
import requests as tt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

get_url=tt.get("https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?rs=ac&len=2&q=batman%20motivation&eq=batman%20moti&etslf=5839&term_meta[]=batman%7Cautocomplete%7Cundefined&term_meta[]=motivation%7Cautocomplete%7Cundefined")
soup=BeautifulSoup(get_url.text,"html.parser")
er=[]
select_css=soup.select("script#jsInit1")[0]
for i in select_css:
    er.append(json.loads(i))
```

Comment: Have you tried using ```.join()```

Comment: Yes , I tried .

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

Comment: Can you share the content of `select_css` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , so i wanted to save the output in any variable , then i pass the select_css to a function and instead of appending i return the data then gave a reference (closure) to that function and used the returned output with some operations.

```
import requests as tt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

get_url=tt.get("https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?rs=ac&len=2&q=batman%20motivation&eq=batman%20moti&etslf=5839&term_meta[]=batman%7Cautocomplete%7Cundefined&term_meta[]=motivation%7Cautocomplete%7Cundefined")
soup=BeautifulSoup(get_url.text,"html.parser")
er=[]
select_css=soup.select("script#jsInit1")[0]


def hello(x):
    for i in x:
        return json.loads(i)

desired_variable=hello(select_css)

print(desired_variable['tree']['data']['results'][2]['images']['orig']['url'])
```